# Virtual Key Codes: Same across ALL PC's

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-xp

On different Windows OS's & on versions of windows that are running different langauges(keyboards, encoding etc.) are the virtual key codes always the same?

So from looking at MSDN I can see that VK_RETURN = 0x0D. Will the Return key always have this value regardless of what version of windows or language or etc.?

MSDN Virtual Key Codes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the point of having virtual keys in the first place.  There are a whole heckofalot of complications to turn a virtual key into a real key, `WM_CHAR`.  That's keyboard layout nightmare.  You don't have to fear `VK_RETURN`, that one is in the usual place.

Comment: Except many key-symbols are missing, such as question mark. So the vk system does not in fact work. Because the windows way of checking for question mark is to check for shift + slash .... WTF!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, it will.

Otherwise, it would break backwards compatibility, and your software would have to be recompiled for each version of Windows.